# How do closures infer their type based on the trait they're required to implement?

Tags: generics, rust, closures, traits

I'm writing a function that accepts different trait implementors. One of them is a closure. Some closures need an argument type annotation and some don't, depending on their bodies.

Example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44b8a784348d488df9f1bd3201f045a8)):

```
fn main() {
    bar(|x| x);
    bar(|x: bool| !x); // Why is the annotation needed?
}

trait Foo<T> {
    type Output;
}

impl<F: Fn(T) -> O, T, O> Foo<T> for F {
    type Output = O;
}

fn bar(_: impl Foo<bool, Output = bool>) {}
```

- Why do some closures infer the argument type and others need annotation?
- Is it possible to redesign trait or function to never require annotation?

My (invalid) reasoning is that inference is the same for both closures:

1. `bar` needs `Foo<bool, Output = bool>`
2. Only `Fn(bool) -> bool` implements `Foo<bool, Output = bool>`
3. The closure must be `|bool| -> bool`

The fact that negation (`Not` trait) detaches the input type from the output type should not matter, but it seems to somehow be a crucial element.

Comment: because `!` is not implemented for T ?

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. Replacing `!x` with `x | true` removes need for annotation and `BitOr` is not implemented for `T` either.

Comment: You are already setting `x`'s type implicitly by doing this.  `x | true`, check the `BitOr`'s defintion type of `x` is the same with right operand's type.

Comment: Right operand is `Self` by default, but it can be any type, it's even written explicitly in  [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitOr.html). Output type may be none of input types as well.

Comment: Your bar function expects closure which needs to return bool and there is only single BitOr<T> implementation for bool which T is a bool .

Comment: I've added a struct, which implements `BitOr<bool, Output = bool>` and it still compiles with no annotation when closure is `|x| x | true`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c97ad3393c74b3b293d7f80c367b98df)

Comment: @CodeSandwich I realized that your bar fn also uses Foo<bool, i was considering it as Foo<T, so BitOr should act like that already, but i added some other options which works, it gets interesting please check :  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd399a15e9401b56aad814b24f02b081)

Comment: @ÖmerErden Good one! I've got a feeling that this question will end up as a Rust issue.

Comment: Interestingly `|x| !&x` works, but `|x| !*&x` doesn't.

Comment: Given this discussion, it seems to me that you are hitting a limitation of the type inference algorithm used, rather than a fundamental language rule.

Comment: I've created a Rust [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58834).

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884862/how-does-the-type-deduction-work-in-this-docopt-example/54885365#54885365

Comment: The type of the closure is inferred based on the types of the arguments it takes and the return type of the closure body. Here, negation can change the type of return value. In the case of `Fn(bool) -> bool`, we cannot see the effect of negation on types (as !true is false and !false is true, both of which are boolean), but e.g., unsigned integers, the effect of negation on type can be clearly evident.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a glitch. The Rust-analyzer LSP is able to infer what the type is supposed to be, but for whatever reason the compiler can't.

From what I can tell, this code doesn't compile on any version of Rust, and cannot be automatically fixed with `cargo fix`.

Interestingly, the compiler *does* seem to work on this equivalent code:

```rust
bar(|x| x ^ true);
```